# How to bound a list by enum

Tags: c#

I am trying to bound a list with a enum . Enum have following value

```
public enum Degree
{

    Doctorate = 1,
    Masters = 2,
    Bachelors = 3,
    Diploma = 4,
    HighSchool = 5,
    Others = 6
}
```

and the list is a type of following class

```
class List1
{
    public string Text{get; set;}
    public string Value{get; set;}
}
```

how to map it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
private List<SelectListItem> MapDegree()
        {
            var enumerationValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Degree));
            var enumerationNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Degree));
            List<List1> lists = new List<List1>();
            foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Degree)))
            {
                List1 selectList = new List1
                {
                    Text = value.ToString(),
                    Value = ((int)value).ToString(),

                };
                lists.Add(selectList);
            }
            return lists;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you call `Enum.GetValues` and `Enum.GetNames`, and then not use those values?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a LINQ solution that's nice and simple:

```
var t = typeof(Degree);
var list = Enum.GetValues(t).Cast<int>().Zip(Enum.GetNames(t), 
    (value, name) => new List1{Text = name, Value = value.ToString()}
    ).ToList();
```

This could obviously be turned into an extension method too.

For more information, please see:
[Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx)
[Enum.GetNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx)
[LINQ Enumerable.Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx)

### Update

Since the `Zip` method is only in .NET 4.0, here's an alternative 3.0 way to do it.

```
var t = typeof(Degree);
var list = Enum.GetValues(t).Cast<Degree>().Select(
    value => new List1{ Text = value.ToString(), Value = ((int)value).ToString() }
    ).ToList();
```

If you need a 2.0 answer, look at @Dewasish's answer.

Comment: That does not compile. `Enum.GetValues` returns an Array and there is no `Zip` method available on an Array.

Comment: The `Zip` method is a new extension method in .NET 4.0, so I updated my answer with a pre-4.0 solution that's just as good.

Comment: Even in .NET 4.0, you can't apply `Zip` on an `Array`. `Zip` must be called on a `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @Otiel You are correct.  The array needed a `.Cast<int>()`, and a `.ToString()` too.  Answer updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a utility function to create a Hashtable of the enum.

```
public static class EnumUtil<T>
{
    public static Hashtable ToHashTable()
    {
        string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(T));
        Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            ht.Add(names[i], (int)values.GetValue(i));
        return ht;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
EnumUtil<Degree>.ToHashTable();
```

Comment: I'd suggest the following syntax: `EnumUtil.GetHashTable<Degree>()`.

Comment: You're right, there's no need to make the a generic class when you only need the method to be generic.